# Migrating to Kubernetes, still need Spring Cloud Eureka/Zuul?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

We are in the process of industrialising our first microservices application which is predominantly built using Spring Boot 2. We are currently using Spring Cloud Zuul for our routing and Eureka for service discovery.

We are looking to use Kubernetes on AWS (using EKS). My question is there still value of running Eureka and Zuul for service discovery/routing or can they be replaced by Kubernetes.

Comment: Interesting question! Not sure that I could give the answer but from my knowledge the Kubernates is about running, scheduling and scaling containers but not about routing and discovery. Not sure how right or wrong I'm with that.

Comment: Kubernetes provides all out of the box. I don't have a so deep knowledge of Spring Cloud stack so maybe i can miss some feature offered by the latter that has no k8s equivalent. But in general you can do discovery, routing and load balancing very easly with k8s. You "just" need to change your code, remove a bunch of annotations/ configuration files and write some yaml. It would be reasonable manage a transition between the two approaches. check out something like https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-kubernetes too

Comment: Great thanks, I'll look into spring-cloud-kubernetes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It all depends on what you want to achieve here.

If you have existing applications that are registering themselves with Eureka and you want to use those services, then I'd say yes to have as little impact as possible. If you are only going to use Kubernetes then it could make sense to use its registry. Although there are others (eg. Consul, Eureka, Zookeeper) who would be a better candidate in case you want to have a hybrid system, or if you want to move from Kubernetes to X in the future.

If you want to have an API gateway as entrypoint, then there are a lot of different solutions (Spring Cloud Gateway, Apigee, haproxy, nginx,...) with which you can use the cloud platform load balancers too. Basically you create routes between the endpoint in your API gateway and the address of the load balancer of Kubernetes (service). Now if you want to use smart load balancing, eg. using the circuitbreaker pattern, then I’d leverage the power of service discovery and client-side load balancing and stop using the load balancer of the platform. In the end it all comes down to what functionality you need.

One thing to note is that most of the Spring Cloud Netflix components have entered maintenance mode, see this post: https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/23/spring-cloud-greenwich-release-is-now-available#spring-cloud-netflix-projects-entering-maintenance-mode

Comment: Thanks. There are no existing applications using Eureka so would prefer to make the changes now to prevent duplicating service discovery. We are planning to use AWS API gateway which will route to the 'private' microservices running in Kubernetes. Only thing I need to check is how Feign will interconnect with microservices as currently it uses Eureka too.

Comment: Correct, that would currently be an issue if you don't want to use RestTemplate or something else. However, some changes are currently being made that will allow this in the future, see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/553

Comment: Cheers, I guess next step is to break it and fix it up :)